# Joomla's messing the mobile menu up

Tags: javascript, mobile, joomla, menu, responsive-design

I have multiple issues with this practice site. It worked perfectly fine on desktop until it was loaded on Joomla. Now the menu is always in open state and when I hide it, it hides itself on desktop and tablet too. Boo.

Here's the link to the site: http://dgm3740.inkedkeyboard.com/joomla/

And here's the js script I've been using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$(function(){
        $('#showPhoneNav').click(function() {
            $(".primary-nav").slideToggle('normal', function(){ //Shows Nav area
                if ($('.primary-nav').is(':visible')) {
                    $('#showPhoneNav').text('Hide Menu');
                } else {
                    $('#showPhoneNav').empty();
                    $('#showPhoneNav:first-child').append('<img src="http://dgm3740.inkedkeyboard.com/joomla/templates/varyastemplate/img/menuIcon.png" alt="navigation icon" />');
                } //end of if
            }); //end of slidetoggle
        }); //end of myNav
    //}); //end showPhoneNav
}); //end of ready
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't following. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What **should** be happening with the menu? I've tested it and don't see any issues with it. Also note that you have are importing jQuery twice on your site which may cause conflicts with some scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the URL you provided shows the following basic Javascript error:

```js
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#main-slider').flexslider({
        animation:      "slide",
        slideshowSpeed: 4000, 
        animationSpeed: 300
    })')
```

A quick check of the page shows that `main-slider` is not found anywhere in the html, did you remove it after posting the question?

Alternatively, looking at the headers for that page I can also see that you have both `jQuery` and `Mootools` loaded:

```html
<script src="/joomla/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
...
<script src="/joomla/media/system/js/mootools-core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It could be a conflict between the two (possibly but unlikely) without the `main-slider` element on the page it's hard to resolve the issue further.